# remove pushed item from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I remove pushed item with a specific value?
        I have some pushed items with 2 keys: deviceToken and UserID.
        I need to remove item with the specific deviceToken.

```
    dev-app
        push
            asdasdasdasda(generated key)
                deviceToken: 12345678
                userID: qwerty
            dgfgdfghhdfgd(generated key)
                deviceToken: 87654321
                userID: sdaerty

    I need to remove the the 1-st one (which has a DeviceToken with value "12345678").
```

Comment: What does your data structure look like (add it as text please, no screenshots)? Also: did you try anything already? Firebase has pretty good [documentation on querying](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries) and there are lots of [questions covering Firebase Queries](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+query) too.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
I have edited my question - the structure is higher.
Can you help me please?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the child items based on `deviceToken`, you can execute a query like this:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://dev-app.firebaseio.com/push");
Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("deviceToken").equalTo(12345678);
queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
    System.out.println(snapshot.getKey());
  }
  // ....
});
```

I just copied this snippet from the [Firebase documentation on queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries) and modified it to you data.

Comment: What about the new documentation? Could you provide an example of getting a reference say <firebaseURL>/node/<randomlyGeneratedKey> so that I can use .removeValue() on that inside a listview. My issue is I'm trying to grab the proper pushed key in the list so that I can reference that key under /nodes and then delete that one singular item instead of the entire nodes reference which is what mDatabase.child("nodes").removeValue() does currently. When I want something like mDatabase.child("nodes").child(pushedKey).removeValue(). Do you have any examples of this?

Comment: when i send data to nodes it looks like this. 
mDatabase.child("nodes").push().setValue(POJO);